# How using variable of target in my makefile?

Tags: makefile, target

I write the target in my `makefile` when I follow the example of Linux develop C book. Below is a cut down of the my `makefile`:

```
result:=


all :  
$(result) = $(subst a, A, how are you)

        echo -n "the result is :"
        echo $(result)


.PHONY: all
```

In shell,

```
it@ubuntu:~/luke/c_test$ make -s all
makefile:5: *** empty variable name.  Stop.
```

How could I return the value of function to "result" in target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first assignment is correct. Your second assignment erroneously uses variable interpolation syntax. It's `variable := value` not `$(variable) := value`; the latter would try to use the *value* of `variable` as the name of the variable to assign the value to, but in your case, it's empty.

Assigning the variable inside a recipe is also wrong; the stuff inside a recipe should be tab-indented shell commands.

```
result := $(subst a, A, how are you)

all:
    echo "the result is: $(result)"

.PHONY: all
```

or maybe even inline the function call:

```
    echo "the result is: $(subst a,A,how are you)"
```

It's not completely impossible to assign a variable only for the duration of a single recipe, but I guess you are still trying to learn the basic syntax.

Maybe also notice the difference between `:=` and `=`. The former should be preferred in GNU Make unless you specifically want `make` to evaluate the assignment every time the value is expanded.